# Wordpress Plugin: Event Organiser, How to edit the calendar template

Tags: wordpress, calendar

I am using the event organiser plugin of wordpress and trying to edit the template for the **calendar**. Has anybody an advice how to make changes for the calendar?

Until now i have only inserted the calendar shorttag at the page and the calendar is displayed correctly in the frontend, but now i have to make changes in the markup...

Answer (score 0):

I always use my own css to change the layout, so when an update is posted to the plugin, my code isn't overwritten.

Useful with this is the custom CSS function of http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack-lite/ (with tons of other great stuff) or just use http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Comment: yes.. i have my own css-file where i can add my own styles, but i want to edit the markup or the template of the calendar in this plugin.